# Chasse-Neige in Frozen II?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I was watching [Frozen II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_II) at the cinemas the other day, and I was listening to some of the background music, and I'm pretty sure that I heard Franz Liszt's 12th Transcendental Etude in some of it. It was especially prominent in the scene where
(SPOILER)

> Elsa was putting out the magical fire in the forest with her ice powers

but I can't find the scene online in order to confirm my thoughts yet. If anyone could be able to help it would be appreciated.

Transcendental Etude 12: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFFR0rEW_0I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're referring to this scene -?

> [*Frozen 2 - Elsa Meets The Fire Spirit HD Scene*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLjELdg-4Pg)

I'm quite sure it's not Franz Liszt's *Transcendental Etude No. 12*. It's a bit difficult to make out the background score completely with all the other sounds, but it sounds very different to my ears.

---

*From the [comment](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/9984/chasse-neige-in-frozen-ii/10562#comment14311_10562) below by the OP:*

> Yeah, it's not exactly the same; though it uses the same Db C Bb A pattern (likely in a different key) and similar melodic contours throughout the background. The dynamics and articulations are completely different however.

Comment: Ayy! That is the scene. Yeah, it's not exactly the same; though it uses the same Db C Bb A pattern (likely in a different key) and similar melodic contours throughout the background. The dynamics and articulations are completely different however. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. And the Transcendental Etudes are such a great set of pieces, I'm glad to be able to introduce them to you :)